# Do I need Arduino/Raspberry for every light in my house?

Tags: android, python, arduino, esp8266, home-automation

I am a "tech guy" who wishes to learn about home automation (with HomeAssistant.io). There is something I don't understand yet.

I have seen tutorials about how to make my own home own automation Etc. In all of the tutorials I saw a lot of cables crambeling [??what??] to only switch on a simple light (while the Arduino is connected directly to the light and the Arduino connected with an Ethernet cable to the internet and the light turned on by an Android app).

If I want to do a real home automation I don't want to connect every light in my house with a wire to the Arduino (sounds like a crappy home automation).

I understand that there is something called ESP8266, this is a wireless chip.

My questions:

1. How to connect the ESP8266 to a light in my house without direct (wire) connection to Arduino?
2. How to program it?

Assuming that I will connect the Arduino/Raspberry directly with a wire to the router and my home devices will be without any cables going around the house like a caveman.

In your answer please give some good tutorials.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because home automation wiring is not programming related and the addition question of "How to program it?" is far too broad.

Comment: watch some youtubes about this, there's hundreds. if you have ESPs, you don't need any arduinos; you hook the ESP to a DC input and a relay that controls the AC, or a MOSFET to control DC (like for LED strips). it's all on the wifi. to be clear: you use multiple ESPs, one for each light (i have >70 ATM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control several lights with an Esp2866 or raspberry using wifi and relays outputs, but you have to setup the device on a IOT platform like Blynk Or My Devices Cayenne, both have their own API and documentation you should take a look.

Answer (score 0):

No. In my case I'm using only one RPI with home assistant some sonoff ( that's an esp2866 ) some xiaomi/aqara devices like motion sensors and switches and one broadlink RM pro. With that I'm controlling all the lights of my home and I only have one RPI.

Here you can see the code that I'm using:

https://github.com/miguelfrancisco85/homeassistant